# How to resize an image/chat bubble accordingly?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am making something like the WhatsApp Chat. When you send a message, a greenish rectanglepops up with a small arrow on the top right hand which resizes according to the amount of text you put in.

I would like to ask for help in doing the same using Xamarin Android (C#)

How do I resize a rectangle according to the text one inputs??

Thanks!!

P.S. - Please provide me the greenish color of the rectangle whatsapp uses

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Xamarin does it but in Android we use 9-patch images for these kind of backgrounds. It is very simple actually. You can check the below links.

http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Comment: Can I get a code example?you probably do this in Java??

Answer (score 0):

Using a textview you can set a background for it.
add some padding so the text doesnt go off the edge.
if the background image is a bubble it should stretch to the text.(try use a slightly high res).

Comment: Will it get blurred??